# Duplicate files during packaging of APK or UnsatisfiedLinkError Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Android project which uses libraries with interdependencies:

Android Application depends on the following native libraries

- module tess-two (containing tesseract and leptonica)
- module opencv4android
- module mylibrary

mylibrary also depends on tess-two and opencv4android

The following is the build.gradle file of my Android Application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':libraries:opencv4android')
    compile project(':libraries:tess-two')
    compile project(':libraries:mylibrary')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

//    packagingOptions {
//        exclude 'lib/armeabi/liblept.so'
//        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libtess.so'
//        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/liblept.so'
//        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libtess.so'
//        exclude 'lib/mips/liblept.so'
//        exclude 'lib/mips/libtess.so'
//        exclude 'lib/x86/liblept.so'
//        exclude 'lib/x86/libtess.so'
//    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

A gradle build on this configuration fails with `duplicate files during packaging of APK` error due to `liblept.so` and `libtess.so` being copied twice.

When I uncomment the packaging options I can build successfully, however, I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` at runtime since `liblept.so` and `libtess.so` are not contained in the apk at all.

How can I get `liblept.so` and `libtess.so` to be included in the apk exactly once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, however, I do not quite understand it.

The `build.gradle` files of both modules mylibrary and tess-two contained a definition for

> android.sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']

Commenting this definition in tess-two resulted in `libtess.so`and `liblept.so` being copied to the apk only once.

If someone understands this solution please leave a comment or answer.

Edit:

In the meantime I found a better solution:
I added the following code to my main applications gradle.build file:

```
packagingOptions { // otherwise libtess.so and liblept.so are copied to apk twice resulting in an error
    pickFirst('lib/*/liblept.so')
    pickFirst('lib/*/libtess.so')
}
```